# Why I am not Getting output of NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have one method initWithNSDictionary :

```
- (id) initWithNSDictionary:(NSDictionary*)countryInfo_
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        NSLog(@"Country Info = %@",countryInfo_);
            self.code = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"countryCode"];
            self.name = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"countryName"];
            self.continent = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"continentName"];
            self.region = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"region"];
            self.currencyCode = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"currencyCode"];
            self.population = [countryInfo_  valueForKey:@"population"];
    }
    NSLog(@"code %@", code);

    return self;
}
```

I am accessing this method by :

```
Country *country = [[Country alloc] initWithNSDictionary:jsonObject];
```

After that I am printing this value in label by :

```
countryCode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Country Code = %@", country.code];
```

When I am logging it in console I get :

```
NSLog(@"Currency Code = %@", currencyCode.text);

Currency Code = Currency Code = (
    BRL
)
```

And on actual device screen in label I am only getting :

```
Country Name = (
```

I want output like :

```
Currency Code = BRL
```

CountryInfo_ :

```
Country Info = (
        {
        areaInSqKm = "8511965.0";
        capital = "Bras\U00edlia";
        continent = SA;
        continentName = "America meridionale";
        countryCode = BR;
        countryName = Brasile;
        currencyCode = BRL;
        east = "-32.392998";
        fipsCode = BR;
        geonameId = 3469034;
        isoAlpha3 = BRA;
        isoNumeric = 076;
        languages = "pt-BR,es,en,fr";
        north = "5.264877";
        population = 201103330;
        south = "-33.750706";
        west = "-73.985535";
    }
)
```

And Country code prints :

```
code (
    BR
)
```

why this is happening?

Comment: Currency come in the form of array.. you should change into string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think currencyCode has a `NSString` with newline character
Try this

```
  currencyCode.text = [[[currencyCode.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];`
```

hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I got the required output by adding this. @jagdish

Comment: That's more a "small hack" that a real solution. Modifying the -`description` of objects to get the info is not a good solution.

Comment: with the use of description, the output was same as above. So I had to find new way @Larme

Comment: It's because `jsonObject` is a `NSArray` and not a `NSDictionary`. The issue is that you didn't understood correctly the structure of your JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The actual `CountryInfo_` is an array, not an `NSDictionary`. So instead of passing

```
Country *country = [[Country alloc] initWithNSDictionary:jsonObject];
```

Try passing

```
Country *country = [[Country alloc] initWithNSDictionary:jsonObject[0]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
self.code = [[countryInfo_ objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"countryCode"];
self.name = [[countryInfo_ objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"countryName"];
self.continent = [[countryInfo_ objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"continentName"];
self.region = [[countryInfo_ objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"region"];
self.currencyCode = [[countryInfo_ objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"currencyCode"];
self.population = [[countryInfo_ objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"population"];
```

Comment: It causes the app crash. @koushik Gounder

Comment: So what does this `NSLog(@"Country Info = %@",countryInfo_);` and  `NSLog(@"code %@", code);` print

Comment: Also try this `self.code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",  [countryInfo_  objectForKey:@"countryCode"]];` in case if countryCode is a number make self.code as a NSString

Comment: I have added two logs in my question. @Koushik Gounder

Comment: Tried converting in NSString but it gives same output. @Koushik Gounder

Comment: From the `Country Info =` u sent its an array of `NSDictionary` with only one array Value  so try somethinglike `self.name = [[countryInfo_  objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"countryName"];`

Comment: Thanks. I have got by self.code = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", [countryInfo_ valueForKey:@"countryCode"]];   @Koushik Gounder

Comment: When u log a dictionary it should be like `Country Info = {}` this and not like `Country Info = ( {} )` for an array Nslog value will be like `Country Info = ( {},{})`.